# Delphi define types of external WinAPI function

Tags: delphi, winapi

I was trying to call [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx) function in delphi

My first attempt was as follow

```
function CreateProcessWithLogonW(
  lpUsername,
  lpDomain,
  lpPassword: LPCWSTR;
  dwLogonFlags: DWORD;
  lpApplicationName: LPCWSTR;
  lpCommandLine: LPWSTR;
  dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
  lpEnvironment: Pointer;
  lpCurrentDirectory: LPCWSTR;
  lpStartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  lpProcessInfo: TProcessInformation
  ): BOOL;
    stdcall; external 'Advapi32.dll';
```

I got AV once i call it in my program, I [googled](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/200709/0709089600.html) how to call this function in Delphi and i found that `lpStartupInfo` and `lpProcessInfo` must be define as follow

```
 var lpStartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
 var lpProcessInfo: TProcessInformation
```

The functions works as expected.

My question: How i can now if the function parameter must be variable when calling external WinAPI functions such the above. Because I didn't find in the docs about this information.

Comment: "How i can now if the function parameter must be variable" <-- can you clarify your question a bit.

Comment: The MSDN documentation is clear. The struct args are passed as the address of the struct. Do you read C?

Comment: @theB i mean `var lpProcessInfo: TProcessInformation` or `lpProcessInfo: TProcessInformation`How i can konw the proper type, Maybe i don't know how i can express regarding my question or modeling it but, Because my native language is not the english

Comment: These arguments has to be **by reference** (this includes pointers). Passing **by value** won't work.

Comment: The function is declared completely in JwaWinBase.pas from  https://sourceforge.net/p/jedi-apilib/ => "Code" => "Download Snapshot" and http://blog.delphi-jedi.net/jedi-api-headers/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan @ free-consulting I got it now, Thanks.

Comment: `var lpProcessInfo: TProcessInformation ` - var-parameters and out-parameters are always by-reference.  const-parameters might be both by-value (small ones like integer) and by-reference ( longer ones ). Parameters that are neither const nor var/out would have to be COPIED by Delphi so the function could make the local changes in it. Thus better to avoid them :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The I appreciate your explain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions  and also "calling convention" section at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Calling_Conventions and also http://www.guidogybels.eu/asmch2.html

Comment: @Arioch'The Its really very useful resources for me, Thanks && Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first attempt was close but slightly wrong.  The correct declaration should look like this instead:

```
function CreateProcessWithLogonW(
  lpUsername,
  lpDomain,
  lpPassword: LPCWSTR;
  dwLogonFlags: DWORD;
  lpApplicationName: LPCWSTR;
  lpCommandLine: LPWSTR;
  dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
  lpEnvironment: Pointer;
  lpCurrentDirectory: LPCWSTR;
  lpStartupInfo: PStartupInfoW;
  lpProcessInfo: PProcessInformation
  ): BOOL;
    stdcall; external 'Advapi32.dll';
```

Notice that the last two parameters are pointers (`LP` means pointer in the Win32 API), so you would declare non-pointer variables and then use the `@` operator to pass their memory addresses to the parameters:

```
var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfoW;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  CreateProcessWithLogonW(..., @StartupInfo, @ProcessInfo);
end;
```

However, the parameters are both required and cannot be nil.  In Delphi, it is *customary*<sup>1</sup> to declare a required pointer parameter as a non-pointer `var` parameter instead:

```
function CreateProcessWithLogonW(
  lpUsername,
  lpDomain,
  lpPassword: LPCWSTR;
  dwLogonFlags: DWORD;
  lpApplicationName: LPCWSTR;
  lpCommandLine: LPWSTR;
  dwCreationFlags: DWORD;
  lpEnvironment: Pointer;
  lpCurrentDirectory: LPCWSTR;
  var lpStartupInfo: TStartupInfoW;
  var lpProcessInfo: TProcessInformation
  ): BOOL;
    stdcall; external 'Advapi32.dll';

...

var
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfoW;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
begin
  CreateProcessWithLogonW(..., StartupInfo, ProcessInfo);
end;
```

This is just a convenience, though.  Whether the variables are being passed **by-pointer** or **by-reference**, the same memory addresses are still being passed to the API either way.

<sup>1</sup>: Embarcadero has a bad habit of declaring *optional* pointer parameters (ones that *can* be nil) as `var <type>` in their Win32 API declarations (instead of as `P<type>` or `^<type>`). This makes it harder for users to actually pass nil pointers when they want to (though [it can still be done](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/23006), using an awkward type-cast).

Comment: Well, if docs lists structured argument is optional - leave it as pointer, otherwise translate as byref. Another possibility is add overloaded version.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: overloading can get ugly depending on how many parameters are involved and how many of them are optional vs required. I prefer to translate to the actual types defined in the API (in tis case, pointers) to maintain the API's intended semantics, and ease cross-language translations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want you to know how much I value your support always.